# RGB to grayscale to RGB

Tags: image-processing, mapping, rgb, grayscale

I convert a RGB Image to a grayscale Image using different weights. Now I wish to extract the same RGB values for each corresponding grayscale pixel.

For example :
Step 1 : (32,14,0) ---> 32*a+14*b+0*c ----> P is in the range [0,255] 
{a,b,c is known/same throughout the two steps}

Step 2 : P(same as step 1)= x*a + y*b + z*c ( R1 <= x,y,z <= R2, x,y,z are integers and within a range, which is known to us)

Find the solution to x,y,z such that x = 32, y = 14, z = 0.

Any solutions to this problem or any mapping function/s which (R'G'B' -> Gray -> R'G'B')

Comment: This is clearly not possible in the general case because you've squashed your 3-dimensional information onto a single dimension.  You have discarded information.  Thus there are an infinite number of solutions to `P = x*a  + y*b + z*c`.

Comment: Even if the known information of (a,b,c) in the second step, and with the constraint that [x,y,z] are in a known range?
If not this, are there any possible mapping functions which enable what I wish to achieve?

Comment: Even with these constraints, then In general no.  Imagine a = 2 and b = 1 (let's ignore c for simplicity).  If P = 6, then you have solutions (x = 3, b = 0), (x = 2, b = 2), (x = 1, b = 4), (x = 0, y = 6).  In the specific cases where a and b are co-prime, then things would be different.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the answer!

Comment: Is your goal to encode the RGB values into a single scalar? Something like `R*256*256+G*256+B`, assuming R, G and B are integers in the range 0-255?

Comment: "are there any possible mapping functions which enable what I wish to achieve?": you should be more specific about what you want to achieve.

Comment: Let a=b=c=1. I tell you that aR+bG+cB=143. Guess my R, G, B.

Comment: My goal is to encode RGB into a single scalar yes, with R, G, B values in a range.

Comment: I'll just explain a bit more to make things more clear. I have two sides, a sender and a receiver. The sender encodes rgb->gray, while the receiver performs gray->rgb. Now i have the provision that the sender and receiver can share some information that might help the receiver to exactly decode the initial rgb values. More like a key, by the concept of cryptography.    What I mean by a mapping function is that, gray to rgb conversion takes place with the help of a colormap. My aim would be generate such a colormap which is invertible in nature.

Comment: If you're converting 24-bit RGB to 8-bit grayscale, there's an inevitable information loss.  If in fact you have 24 bits available, then there are trivial solutions (e.g. what CrisLuengo suggested).

Answer (score 2):

The conversion from color to grayscale is irreversible.